# I don't understand touch screen event

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    logArea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logArea);
    //Tocco
    logArea.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(erase) {
                    logArea.setText("");
                    counter = 0;
                }
                logArea.append("DOWN: (" + x + ", " + y + ")    ");
                counter++;
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                logArea.append("MOVE: (" + x + ", " + y + ")    ");
                counter++;
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                counter++;
                logArea.append("UP: (" + x + ", " + y + ")  Contatore: " + counter);
                erase = true;

                break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Now I run my application and keep still my finger on the screen of the phone. The event perceived is MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and also a series of events MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE. Multiple pairs of points are returned and not only a coordinate pair as I expected.
If I run the application on the simulator is returned only a point and an event MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN as I expected. Why?
I need necessarily only one point (one in the middle of a finger if possible or close) because I have to read his exact color to do something.
Works on the emulator, not on the device.
What can I do to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that you get a different point each time you get the event? Maybe that's because you can't hold your finger perfectly still and apply pressure uniformly at all times?

Comment: Probably so. But then how do I tell whether I stopped or I'm moving ever so slightly in an image?

Answer (score 1):

What I do to limit the precision of my touch events is to store the last touch, get a delta from the last to the current, and then test if it is past my precision level.  I got this idea (and I believe I didn't even have to change the code much) from the SDK samples, so at least in older versions of the platform (pre-multi touch) this was a good recommended practice.

If your issue is happening because of multi touch, you might have to do some tracking with MotionEvent.getPointerXYZ() methods (only considering ACTION_MOVE events associated with the original pointer id you start tracking in your first ACTION_DOWN event)

```
private float mX, mY;
private static float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 5;  

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}
private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        // do my stuff here...
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCount%28%29

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerId%28int%29